# How to see a function is $C^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, greens-function

Let $\phi_{z}(w)=\frac{z-w}{1-w\bar{z}}$ which is a conformal mapping of $\mathbb{D}$. $f\in C(\bar{\mathbb{D}})\cap C^2(\mathbb{D})$. $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk centered at the origin in the complex plane. $dA(w)$ is the normalized lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{D}$.

Define $G[f](z)=\int_{\mathbb{D}}(\log|w|^2)f({\phi}_z(w))\frac{(1-|z|^2)^2}{|1-w\bar{z}|^4}\,dA(w)$ , how to see that $G[f]\in C^2(\mathbb{D})$?

I encounter this statement in a proof of a theorem related to Green function. The author says it is clearly to get the twice continuity. But i really can not see why. Please help.

Comment: not so different of $\int_D \frac{1}{|1-w z|^4} dA(w)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009.what is your point?

Comment: For continuity it seems you can use Lebesgue dominated convergence to show that if $z_n\to z_0\in\Bbb{D}$ then the integrals $G[f](z_n)$ converge to $G[f](z_0)$.  Everything under the integral sign is bounded for $z$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$ except the logarithm, and that's integrable and independent of $z$.  Also, the integrand is continuous in $z$ for fixed $w$.  For differentiability you could presumably write out difference quotients and find a dominating function for them.

Comment: @ForgotALot.Thank you. I will give a try.